# A Matrix combining function R

Tags: r, function, vector, matrix

**The goal:** Eventually produce an R package that allows the user to run a series of "games". In the game, two players are pitted against each other, and in each round (100 total) players select to play C or D. These are done through move sets, which take the form of either

(1) a predefined list of selections between "C" or "D", i.e. a vector of 50 "C"s and then 50 "D"s or

(2) a set of logical instructions like, Round 1 play "C", R2 play "C" if opponent played "C" in R1 else play "D", R3-R99 play randomly, R100 always play "D".

There are 4 possible outcomes in every round.

P1's choice |P2's choice == [P1 score] [P2 score]

```
C|C==[3][3]

C|D==[0][5]

D|C==[5][0]

D|D==[1][1]
```

**Where I'm at:**

I've got down the part where a vector of Cs and Ds is combined into a matrix of paired Cs and Ds.

Code:

```
   #Sample Strategies#
p1 <- c("C","D","C","D","D")
p2 <- c("D","D","D","D","D")
p3 <- c("C","C","C","C","C")
p4  <-c("D","D","C","D","C")

#Combining into a matrix#
gameboard<-cbind(p1, p2, p3, p4, deparse.level = 1)

#First Part of Function#
my_game <- function(trial, n_samples, dat) {
  # as per my comment, generate the game result and name using the colnames directly
  game <- sample(colnames(dat), n_samples)
  list_name <- paste0("", paste(game, collapse=" V "))
  game_result <- paste(dat[, game[1]], 
                       dat[, game[2]], 
                       sep='')
  
  # return both the name and the data in the format desired to parse out later
  return(list(list_name, game_result))
}
#Second Part of the Function#
my_game_wrapper <- function(trials, n_samples, dat) {
  # for multiple trials we create a list of lists of the results and desired names
  results <- lapply(1:trials, my_game, n_samples, dat)
 
  # extract the names and data
  result_names <- sapply(results, '[', 1)
  result_values <- sapply(results, '[', 2)
  
  # and return them once the list is pretty.
  names(result_values) <- result_names
  return(result_values)
}

#Applying the function#
result<-my_game_wrapper(10, 2, gameboard)

Dataframing it
coolresults<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, result))
```

**What I lack**

The tallying of the scores function.

What the new matrix should look like.

```
               P1         P2
Round1 [CD]     0          5
Round2 [DD]     1          1
Etc
```

But let's say that there are 30 players and each one is going to play each other player and itself. I guess that will mean 900 matrices, correct? So, also creating a super matrix of each player's total score after 100 rounds would be more helpful.

Scores are row player's total score when it played column player:

```
        P1      P2    P3     P4     P5

P1     462    453    252    560    600

P2     301    242    437    555    439

P3     232    522    555    232    527

P4     etc

P5
```

Comment: in the matrix of the second code block, why isn't turn 2 `0, 5` instead of `1, 1` according to `CD` in the previous block?  `1` isn't in any of the options you listed.  Also, I think you may be better served taking a step further back and explaining the full problem you're trying to solve.  This is rapidly becoming contrived...

Comment: It should be 0,5. My mistake. I agree in present form it is contrived. I had earlier created a more theoretical and explanatory question, but it had been flagged, placed on hold, and more or less told not to repost as being "not actually a question". So, I'm trying hard to work within the bounds of SO. I'll try.